# HBase Secondary Index using coprocessor

Tags: hbase, secondary-indexes

I am implementing secondary index for a HBase table using coprocessor. Once the rowkey is put in the index table, will it automatically scan the index table if the primary table is scanned. How does the linking happen?
 I am referring to the implementation here
https://itpeernetwork.intel.com/coprocessor-based-secondary-index-on-hbase/

Is this still a valid solution to filter data using non rowkey quickly ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to filter data based on columns, you can check Apache phoenix. It basically uses same mechanism of co-processor.